# Session ID on page reload

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, session, session-cookies, sessionid

I have some questions in mind.

1. Whether Session id is generated only once ?
2. Whether Session id is generated again when we refresh(F5) the page ?
3. Whether Session id is generated again when we reload(Ctrl + F5) the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION is a superglobal array which is destroyed only when browser is closed or when you manually destroy the session.

Whenever you send a http request and create a session variable,you indirectly manipulate a file on server which has all data related to your session.Refreshing the page wont generate a new session,instead it will use the same session that you created earlier.

ctrl + 5(hard reload) :will clear the cache,not the session variables.

f5 : simple reload will just reload the page with a possibility that static content might be served by browsers cache

> Whether Session id is generated only once ?

ANS : Yes

> Whether Session id is generated again when we refresh(F5) the page ?

ANS : No

> Whether Session id is generated again when we reload(Ctrl + F5) the
>   page ?

ANS : No

Comment: Thank you sir :) I have one more doubt. When we hard reload(Ctrl+f5), whether all files in the cache are deleted or only the files that have been modified is deleted ?

Comment: Its is not that everything in the cache will be deleted,but you images and javascript files,css files will be re downloaded..

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference F5 or Ctrl+F5. Session generated only once, when you call session_start() at your script.

If you want to regenerate your session, you must call session_regenerate_id() or kill and start session again

Answer (score 0):

1. session is generated only once. session is generated when you run your script for first time.

2, 3. session id is not generated again when you press F5 or (CTRL + F5)